Power BI/DAX: dynamically filter table values with slicer
I have a Power BI table visual with a column "Monthly Report" containing text values such as "2024 08 August" "2024 09 September", etc...
There is an associated column "Monthly Rank" with numerical values associated with each distinct value from "Monthly Report"(In the data, any row with a "Monthly Report" column value of "2024 09 September" has a "Monthly Rank" column value of 12. Data rows with "2024 05 May" values in the "Monthly Report" column have "Monthly Rank" values of 8).
In the table visual, I'm able to show only the most recent 6 "Monthly Report" values by applying a filter: a column in the data that returns a "Last 6 Months" value...(finds max report date, returns "Monthly Rank" value from that, then Monthly Rank must be equal or no less than 5 less.) All other Monthly Rank values return NULL and NULL is unchecked in the visual filter.
The above is successful in that if the most recent Monthly Report value is "2024 09 September", only that month and the previous 5 month's reports are present in the table.

I would like improve this visual by using a Power BI slicer to select a particular "Monthly Report" value, which would then alter which "Monthly Report" values are shown in the table by showing the selected "Monthly Report" value last, with the 5 prior values preceding.
For instance, if the slicer is filtered to "2024 07 July", only 6 values would be present in the "Monthly Report" column of the table...top to bottom as "2024 02 February", "2024 03 March", "2024 04 April", "2024 05 May", "2024 06 June", and "2024 07 July".
If the slicer value is changed to "2024 10 October" then the 6 values in the table would be:
"2024 05 May", "2024 06 June", "2024 07 July", "2024 08 August", "2024 09 September", "2024 10 October".
I've tried various created measures and columns with DAX to achieve the above but can't find any info on either returning an array of the 6 Monthly Rank values or being able to assign a created column value of "Filtered 6" that would populate based off of the SELECTEDVALUE of the filter.
Oddly enough, this is relatively easy to replicate in Excel, using "List Data Validation" and some simple XLOOKUP formulas.


The dropdown filter in I1 produces the 6 values in L2:L7.
I'm racking my brain for a way to reproduce this Excel logic in SQL but can't figure it out.
Any/all help appreciated.
